# Unable to search queries from database in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on rails to search the desired results. I have a table called coordinates, and I want a search form for that my `model.rb`

```
class Coordinates<ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city , :latitude, :longitude
end
```

**coordinates_controller.rb**

```
class CoordinatesController<ApplicationController
  def show
    @coordinates=Coordinates.where("city = ?", params[:search]).all
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "coordinates", action: "show"}, method: "get") do  %>
<%= label_tag(:coordinates,"search for:") %>
<%= text_field_tag(:show) %>
<%= submit_tag("search") %>
<% end %>
```

**search.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @coordinates.search do |coordinates| %>
  <ul>
    <li><%= coordinates.latitude %></li>
    <li><%= coordinates.longitude %></li>
    <li><%= coordinates.longitude %></li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

but I am getting this error:

> undefined method `search' for []:Array

.. please help

Comment: What do you want to do in `search.html.erb`? Do you want to view filtered `@coordinates`?

Comment: in search.html.erb i want to display the search results. i.e if a city s entered in the search box i want to display  all the matching results  for eg if bangalore s entered it should display the latitude,longitude of bangalore which s already in the table

Comment: So follow @Salil answer.

Comment: tats  not working i tried tat also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin, try changing the form code in `index.html.erb` from:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "coordinates", action: "show"}, method: "get") do  %>
  <%= label_tag(:coordinates,"search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:show) %>
  <%= submit_tag("search") %>
<% end %>
```

To:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "coordinates", action: "show"}, method: "get") do  %>
  <%= label_tag(:search,"search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:search) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

This will populate params[:search] with the value of the text field. Currently you are passing your query as params[:show].

Next, try changing your search results view to:

```
<% @coordinates.each do |coordinates| %>
  <ul>
    <li><%= coordinates.latitude %></li>
    <li><%= coordinates.longitude %></li>
    <li><%= coordinates.longitude %></li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

This iterates over the `@coordinates` collection returned by your controller.

Comment: tried tat also. it says  undefined method 'each' in nil:Nilclass

Comment: @user2492854 are you sure you put this code in correct place?

Comment: there is no way you are getting `@coordinates` as a `nil` because `@coordinates=Coordinates.where("city = ?", params[:search]).all` will always return array

Answer (score 1):

From the line
undefined method 'each' in nil:Nilclass

It seems that there are no coordinates for the city you looking for in your database

after the call 
@coordinates=Coordinates.where("city = ?", params[:search]).all

check `@coordinates.nil?` and `@coordinates.count` to see if this is the case 
And beside it is a better practice to check it before using it - so you can handle it in the way you want - in case that something went wrong in your DB and you don't want the user to get such errors on production

Comment: Are you sure if no coordinates for the city then`@coordinates=Coordinates.where("city = ?", params[:search]).all` will return `nil` ?